# Bitmap to Mat gives wrong colors back

Tags: java, android, bitmap, mat

So I make a bitmap from a blob with the next code:

```
byte[] blob = contact.getMP();
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
Bitmap scalen = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 320, 240, false);
```

and it gives back the next output, which is good

[image]

Then I do the following to make the bitmap into a Mat, but then my colors just change...

```
//Mat ImageMat = new Mat();
Mat ImageMat = new Mat(320, 240, CvType.CV_32F);
Utils.bitmapToMat(scalen, ImageMat);
```

I have no idea why, nor another way to make the bitmap into a Mat. What is wrong?
[image]

Comment: Looks like the blue and red channels are swapped. Are you sure your Mat is storing image as RGB (Java's default) instead of BGR (Opencv's default)

Comment: any updates on this question ?

Comment: Have you found solution for this? i am facing same problem.

Comment: As a side note:

1) I believe your commented line is better

2) `Mat ImageMat = new Mat(320, 240, CvType.CV_32F);` will allocate a matrix which is not suitable to receive the output of `bitmapToMat`, the type should be `CV_8UC4`. Coincidentally the same number of bytes :)

See doc https://iopencv.com/docs/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/Utils.html

Answer (score 14):

The format of color channels in Android Bitmap are **RGB**
But in opencv Mat, the channels are **BGR** by default.

So when you do Utils.bitmapToMat(), [B,G,R] values are stored in [R,G,B] channels. The red and blue channels are interchanged.

One possible solution is to apply cvtcolor on the opencv Mat you got as below:
**Imgproc.cvtColor(ImageMat, ImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);**

It worked for me.

Comment: Fun fact: Android.camera2 jpegs converted to bitmaps and then converted to mats keep their RGB channels in tact.

Comment: Need to be double-confirmed, but it seems Utils.bitmapToMat creates RGB Mat. ( https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp#L45 )

Comment: `Imgproc.cvtColor(ImageMat, ImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);` will a eat lot of cpu time