# Android picture has red tint after decoding and pulling the .png file from the emulator to pc

Tags: android

I am transferring some data from a server ( java app ) to client ( android app ). 
The data gets Base64 encoded, sent, received correct, decoded ( correct ? ) and stored to the device ( correct ? )

I am using android studio and an AVD to simulate it. I take the pictures via DDMS from the virtual device folder to my computers harddisk in order to take a look at them. Is maybe there the problem?

now in the following code sections the picture files get decoded and stored to the device.
Cant figure out where the mistake is.

Would be glad about any hint.

[image: orignial]

[image: after decoding and storing it to device]

```
         byte[] imageBackToByt = Base64.decode(parts[9], Base64.DEFAULT);

         Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBackToByt, 0, imageBackToByt.length);

         File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Android/data/"
                        + ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/Files");

         File imageFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + voReceived.name + ".png");

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(ctx.getString(R.string.SLDMP), "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(ctx.getString(R.string.SLDMP), "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

This is how i encode it on the server in JAVA:

```
            BufferedImage originalPicture = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] pictureInByte = null;
            String pictureEncoded = null;

            try {
                // load the original picture from the filepath
                originalPicture = ImageIO.read(picturFile);

                // Convert the original picture from .png format to byte array (byte []) format
                ImageIO.write(originalPicture, "jpg", byteArrayOS );
                pictureInByte = byteArrayOS.toByteArray();

                // Encode the byte array pictureInByte to String based on Base64 encoding
                pictureEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pictureInByte);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                // If picture failed to load / encode store string "PICTUREERROR" as an error code
                pictureEncoded = "PICTUREERROR";

            }
```

Comment: What happens if you display the bitmap directly to an imageview before you save it to PNG? Does it also show up as the wrong colors? I'm guessing your server and client are using different color formats, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629707/bitmap-to-mat-gives-wrong-colors-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server puts the bytes of the image file in a buffer and sends the contents of the base 64 encoded buffer to the client. Now on client side you should directly decode base 64 all bytes and write all the resulting  bytes to file. In this way you have exactly the same file. All bytes are the same and file size would be equal too.

Instead you use BitmapFactory to construct a Bitmap and then compress it to PNG. That all makes no sense.

If you want to transfer a file then do not use BitmapFactory and Bitmap.

Having said that.. Mmmmm nice filter! The result is wonderfull!

Comment: Thank you greenapps! i did as u said, replaced, bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos); , with  fos.write(imageBackToByt); , but still the same result. i also noticed. the pics in the server are about 250 KB , on the device only 25KB.

Comment: That should do it. As i said before the two files should be identical. Then you did something not according the protocol. Please show in a new code block the Android code. Show the complete reading loop please. What is this parts[9]? Compare also the length of the base64 string sent and base64 string received.

Comment: I see now that on server side you load a png file in memory then compress it to jpg and then send it to the android client which should save the bytes directly in a file with jpg extension. PNG files need more bytes then JPG files for the same image. Factor ten? Mmmm that's much. But this could be what is happening. Dont compress to jpg on serve.. Just send the  bytes of the png file. You have them already in originalPicture. But im not shure. Change your server code to read the bytes directly in a byte buffer and then send that buffer. So also on server side do away with image components.

Comment: Thanks, it did the job! I changed the server as u suggested to the following code.  Please edit your answer so i can mark it as the correct one  pictureInByte = Files.readAllBytes(picturFile.toPath());
     
     // Encode the byte array pictureInByte to String based on Base64 encoding
     pictureEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pictureInByte);

Comment: Very good. Now you could analyse where this coloring effect was caused by. I think on server side.